# Am I reading the Balanced Brackets challenge wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I'm doing the Balanced Brackets problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets) and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

e.g.

```
3
{[()]}
{[(])}
{{[[(())]]}}
```

-->

```
YES
NO
YES
```

I thought it would be a straightforward fact that the string contains balanced brackets if and only if for every pair `s[i],s[n-i-1]` it is true that `s[i]` is a right-facing bracket and `s[n-i-1]` is the corresponding left-facing bracket.

Hence my solution

```
static readonly Dictionary<char,char> brackets = new Dictionary<char,char>() 
{
    { '{', '}' },
    { '[', ']' },
    { '(', ')' }
};

static bool IsBalanced(string str)
{
    for(int i = 0, j = str.Length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)
        if(!brackets.ContainsKey(str[i]) || brackets[str[i]] != str[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

which for some reason is failing.

Comment: `()()` is balanced.

Comment: Also, your algorithm would accept an odd length string with any random character in the middle position.

Comment: Hint: Consider using a stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical implementation is based on *stack*:

- push any *opening* `[`, `{`, `(` bracket to the stack
- on *closing* `]`, `}`, `)` bracket, try to pop the top item and check if it corresponds to the current closing bracket: `(` to `)` etc.. return `false` if stack is *empty* or there's *no correspondence*.
- finally, the stack should be *empty* after the last character has been processed.

Implementation:

```
private static Dictionary<char, char> openByClose = new Dictionary<char, char>() {
  { '}', '{' }, 
  { ']', '[' }, 
  { ')', '(' },
};

private static bool IsBalanced(string source) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    return true;

  Stack<char> brackets = new Stack<char>();

  foreach (char ch in source) {
    char open;

    if (openByClose.Values.Contains(ch)) // ch is an opening bracket
      brackets.Push(ch);
    else if (openByClose.TryGetValue(ch, out open)) // ch is a closing bracket
      if (!brackets.Any())
        return false; // too many closing brackets, e.g. "())"
      else if (brackets.Pop() != open)
        return false; // brackets don't correspond, e.g. "(]"
  }

  return !brackets.Any(); // too many opening brackets, e.g. "(()"
}
```

Comment: That dictionary initialisation hurts my head to look at! :)

Comment: @Chris: Thank you! *Readability* must be, esp. in case of such initialization

Comment: Nice. I have to admit I was thinking there wasn't going to be a nice way to make it more readable but you did the job nicely. Sadly I have already +1ed the post so a +1 to the comment is all the reward I an give you for your efforts. :)

Comment: You can make the initialization bett^H^H^H^Hdifferent with the use of the new dictionary initialization syntax: `['}'] = '{'. See how much better that looks? :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is your code getting Wrong Answer?

You are getting wrong answer on case `str = "()()"`.

#### Solution of the problem

You can solve for using recursion.
Let `isBalanced(l, r)` is whether the string `str[l] + str[l+1] + ... + str[r-1]` is balanced, you can do like this code (c++) and calculate `isBalanced(0, str.Length)`.

```
bool isBalanced(int l, int r) {
    if(l == r) return true;
    int depth = 0, prevptr = l;
    for(int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '(' || str[i] == '{' || str[i] == '[') depth++;
        else depth--;
        if(i != r - 1 && depth == 0) {
            if(!isBalanced(prevptr, i + 1)) return false;
            prevptr = i + 1;
        }
    }
    if(depth != 0) return false;
    if(prevptr != l) {
        if(!isBalanced(prevptr, r)) return false;
        return true;
    }
    bool ok = false;
    if(str[l] == '(' && str[r - 1] == ')') ok = true;
    if(str[l] == '{' && str[r - 1] == '}') ok = true;
    if(str[l] == '[' && str[r - 1] == ']') ok = true;
    if(!ok || !isBalanced(l + 1, r - 1)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

I know you are C# coder, but many C# coder can read C++ code, so I implementated with C++ (because I'm a C++ coder)

Answer (score 0):

## i have solved this problem in javascript by using stack

```
class Stack extends Array {
    constructor(...ele) {
        super(...ele)
    }
    pop()
    {
        if(this.length === 0) throw new Error("nothing to pop");
        super.pop()
     }
    peek() {
        if(this.length === 0) throw new Error("stack is empty");
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
    size() {
        return this.length;
    }
}

const string1 = '{[]}'
function check(string) {
    const stack = new Stack();
    const arr = string.split('');
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        const currentItem = arr[i];
        if(currentItem === '{' || currentItem === '[' || currentItem === '(') {
            stack.push(currentItem);
        }
        else {  // ],},)
            if(stack.size() === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            const lastItem = stack.peek();
            stack.pop();
            if(lastItem === '{' && currentItem === '}')
            {
                //ok
            }
            else if(lastItem === '[' && currentItem === ']'){
                //ok
            }
            else if(lastItem === '(' && currentItem === ')') {
                //ok
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (stack.size() !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(check(string1))
```